# Determine scalability between two numbers

Tags: logarithms

This may seem like basic math, but I'm trying to determine the relationship between the following sets of numbers to understand how they scale. I would like to write an equation to output *y* when given *x*, as follows:

when *x* = `1366`, *y* = `4.67`

when *x* = `1700`, *y* = `5.0`

when *x* = `2106.45`, *y* = `5.33`

I would like an equation that generates the *y* above when given *x*, in the context of the relationship between these numbers. I'm stumped.

--

I explored logarithmic functions but wasn't able to come up with anything, and the only constant I was able to solve for was `1.16237188872621`, which appears to be the factor by which the ratio between *x* and *y* here increments by... e.g.

```
1366 / 4.67 = 292.5053533191
1700 / 5.0 = 340
2106.45 / 5.33 = 395.2063789869
```

```
292.5053533191 * 1.16237188872621 = 340
340 * 1.16237188872621 = 395.2063789869
```

...and so on. Thanks for any help with this!

Comment: A good fit is given by $$f(x)=1.523 \cdot\ln(0.0156x)$$

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Can you explain how you got to these numbers (based on my numbers above)?

Comment: Sure, I used the following command in Mathematica: `FindFit[{{1366,4.67},{1700,5.0},{2106.45,5.33}}, a Log[Abs[b] x],{a,b},x]` For more information, have a look here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFit.html

Comment: By the way, there is also curve fitting in Python: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

Answer (score 1):

For example:
$$y=\frac{(x-1700)(x-2106.45)}{(1366-1700)(1366-2106.45)}\cdot4.67+\frac{(x-1366)(x-2106.45)}{(1700-1366)(1700-2106.45)}\cdot5.0+$$
$$+\frac{(x-1366)(x-1700)}{(2106.45-1366)(2106.45-1700)}\cdot5.33.$$

Comment: Forgive me, but how can I use this in to output *y* when I have *x*?
For example, if *x* = `3000`, what would *y* equal?

Comment: @Zachary Beschler Just substitute! I am ready to write a full expression for the function.

Comment: My math skills are pretty elementary, apologies, I'm trying to keep up, but—substitute what exactly?

Comment: @Zachary Beschler I wrote a full expression. Now, substitute $x=1366.$ What did you get?

Comment: It worked! Is there a way to simplify this to only use one set of numbers?

e.g.:

when *x* = `1366`, *y* = `4.67`

and

when *x* = `1700`, *y* = `5.0`

Comment: It should be noted that, even though this function fits perfectly onto the three given points, it is not clear if the function has the desired global properties

Comment: @Zachary Beschler It works for any $n$ numbers. It names Lagrange polynomial.